# how to apply sumif in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a data of employees, each employee record have his city name, birth date (dd/mm/yyyy) and the salary.

I want to sum the salaries of all employees from "aaa" city and born in 1983.

how I can do that?

Comment: There are plenty of documentation on the web, plus you might look into `SUMIFS` instead which allows for multiple criteria (both city and date, whereas `SUMIF` can only take one criteria). It's really easy to use once you understand how the function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sum base on multiple criteria you should use the `SUMIFS` function. Please find an example below:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B3,C1:C3,"denver",D1:D3,"4/14/1999")
```

**In this example:**

`B1:B3` - is the `SUM` Range (it contains the salaries)

`C1:C3` - is the Criteria Range (it contains the cities)

`"denver"` - is the criteria for the city

`D1:D3` - is the Criteria Range for the date of birth

`"4/14/1999"` - is the Criteria for date of birth

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I will use that type of formatting now.